# Hosting a web server on a network I cant forward on

Tags: networking, web, raspberry-pi, port, portforwarding

Im trying to find a way to host a web server (flask app on raspberry pi) at home. The problem is that my apartment complex provides internet to me and so my public IP is that of the apartment router.

When I go to the public IP, instead of seeing my webpage, I see the login to my apartment's router. This is obviously because that router isn't set up to forward port 80 to my personal router.

I dont really feel comfortable asking the property manager to open forward all incoming port 80 traffic to me, nor do I think they would do it.

So what are my options here? How can I route the traffic from my webpage to just my router?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear: if you are behind a router, it needs to be configured to redirect port to your computer. That is the purpose of a router. And the first benefit is that it protects you against outside attacks.

So you have 2 options:
 1. ask who ever manage the router to configure redirection (maybe you could ask for another port than 80?)
 2. deploy your web-server on the cloud

Otherwise, maybe you could get another internet connection (wireless?)